# Compiler circular reference

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, struct

I defined two types in my code.

```
typedef struct Project Project;

typedef struct Worker{
  Project projects[10];
}Worker;

struct Project{
 Worker member[30];
}
```

The compilation process is throwing the following  error:

> array type has incomplete element type

I think is because of the circular reference, when the compiler is trying to allocate space to the array it does not know the type Project, and the same thing will happen if I change the definition order of the types. 
Am I right about the problem? And most important, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: what do you want the classes to hold? I agree with the compiler, i also crash trying to understand what you want.

Comment: You probably want to use `Project *projects[10]` in `Worker` and/or `Worker *member[30]` in projects. How could it work, otherwise, regarding the memory layout? If you don't specify a pointer, you request that the member be embedded in the struct. So you declared a project to contain 10 workers, which contain 10 further projects, which contain 30 workers, and so on. The recursion doesn't terminate.

Comment: @user4815162342: Another idea would be to keep `Worker` and `Project` separate and introduce a `Relation` class that maps them to each others.

Comment: Should this be C or C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct. Your Worker struct contains the member of type Project by value. In order for the compiler to construct the Worker objects correctly it needs to know it size. This means it needs to have the complete definition of Project type - and in your code it's defined only a few lines later.
You can go around this by using by having reference/pointer to a Project members in Worker struct and using forward declaration to announce it so the compiler will know it's a known type (the problem above is avoided since size of a pointer is independent of type it points to thus the compiler doesn't need the full type definition).

Something like this:

```
struct Project;  //forward declaration of Project type
typedef struct Worker{
  Project *projects[10];
} Worker;

struct Project{
  Worker member[30];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As was mentioned in the comments, both the struct types should hold *pointers* to the other type. As it stands, both `Project` and `Worker` structs would have to be infinitely large, because each `Worker` would contain ten `Project`s, which would contain 30 `Worker`s, etc.

Comment: Or, better, both should hold pointers to each other. There's no real good reason for them to logically contain each other.

Comment: @nneonneo: true, but it might be more efficient to store one inside the other.

Comment: It's OO design I'm worried about, not efficiency. It makes no sense for projects to contain workers, since a worker can be on multiple projects; by similar logic, it makes no sense for workers to contain projects.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare an array of type `Project`, compiler needs to know the definition so as define the `Worker`. With your you forward declaration of `Project`, you are only informing the compiler about the existence of `Project`, but it needs to know the complete definition. You can declare a pointer instead and do `malloc`.

```
typedef struct Project Project;

typedef struct Worker{
  Project *projects;
}Worker;

struct Project{
 Worker *member;
};
```

Side note: a semicolon is missing in your struct definition:

```
struct Project{
 Worker member[30];
};
```

Comment: This is C++; recommend `new` instead of `malloc`.

Comment: @nneonneo `C` tag is also there!

Comment: I know...I hate it when people do that.

Comment: you hate malloc or C/C++ together? :D

Comment: typedef is not a forward declaration

Comment: C/C++ together. I usually use C, so me and `malloc` are mostly good friends.

Comment: @icepack `typedef` serves the same purpose here. Without it, the posted code above would give an error.